# How do I install the Cisco Anyconnect VPN client?

Tags: software-installation, vpn, cisco, vpnc

I installed Cisco AnyConnect for Ubuntu(64) 12.04, but it failed. It can be installed on Ubuntu 10.10(64).

The error log

```
Installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client ...
Extracting installation files to /tmp/vpn.teuSIr/vpninst096243274.tgz...
Unarchiving installation files to /tmp/vpn.teuSIr...
Starting the VPN agent...
/opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I meet that,

```
locate libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
```

So I create symbol link `libxml2.so.2` in `/user/lib` and after I do:

```
Installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client ...
Extracting installation files to /tmp/vpn.5cz4FV/vpninst001442979.tgz...
Unarchiving installation files to /tmp/vpn.5cz4FV...
Starting the VPN agent...
/opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I ensure that there exist lib32 runtime lib on my device.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That ELFCLASS64 seems to suggest you're using a 64bit software on a 32bit OS.  Did yuo make sure you're using the 32bit edition of the software?

Comment: yes, it is really 32bit ediation software.

Comment: i used ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso installed.

`Linux chuck 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`file /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd` 

`/opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped`

From the above info, i confirm that the tool is 32bit edition software, and my os is 64bit.

Comment: i make a problem, i rebuilt lib32-libxml2, and relink tha share lib. Then i found is can be install successfully.

but it still can work normally.
that was strage, From the dmesg, i found vpn module already load.

Comment: i try to manually run vpnui, found some errors.chuck@chuck:/opt/cisco/vpn/bin$ ls
manifesttool  vpn  vpnagentd  vpndownloader  vpndownloader.sh  vpnui  vpn_uninstall.sh
chuck@chuck:/opt/cisco/vpn/bin$ ./vpnui 
./vpnui: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
so i build lib32-atk for that.

Comment: In general, when debugging issues loading shared libraries the `ldd` command can be used to show which libraries fail to resolve.

Answer (score 151):

If you don't need the "official" Cisco AnyConnect VPN software, I highly recommend installing the "network-manager-openconnect-gnome" package in the Ubuntu Repository. It uses OpenConnect which is an open source client for AnyConnect.

Anyhow, that package allows for you to configure and manager your AnyConnect VPN connections through the normal network manager.

I have been using that to connect to my work VPN for the past few months and it has been working great!

You can find the package in the Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic by searching for "OpenConnect."  If you wish to install it via the command-line, you can do so with:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect openconnect
```

For the [GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025115/1175982) you can additionally install the *-gnome package using:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

This adds an option to Network Connections. When you choose to add a connection, there'll be a new option under VPN Connections to add a "Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)". You can then connect to the VPN through the networks applet (in the system tray).

Comment: I use this too in place of the cisco software, but it's really just a workaround.  My University is doing an update of cisco this week and I'm a little antsy it will break the compatability

Comment: This solution did not work for me on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. It did not offer the UI needed to connect, I missed e.g. an option to enter group and user name and password.

Comment: I like this answer (as it worked for me), but feel it's missing half of the explanation. This adds (at least on Linux Mint) an option to Network Connections. When you choose to add a connection, there'll be a new option to add a "Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)". You can then connect to the VPN through the networks applet (in the system tray). This seems the ideal place for it.

Comment: Openconnect GUI via network manager does not allow proxy connections. Only the CLI mode does. This is a drawback for openconnect

Comment: Still works like a charm. Only needed to insert the gateway in NWM and the rest was just point and click the cert, username and password.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer, I have been looking for this ages!

Comment: Downloading  "official" Cisco AnyConnect VPN software is not available for every body. "network-manager-openconnect-gnome" works fantastic. :)

Comment: This ends abruptly for me with `SSL connection failure: A TLS fatal alert has been received.`. If I open the url (vpn.*.*.*) I have in a browser under Windows, there is a Cisco client installation. Could it be that that also installs and configures certificates etc.? Otherwise, I am currently just adding the url under "Gateway". Are none of the other fields important? A group name is the only other detail I have.

Answer (score 35):

Use openconnect! quite easy!

1. First run command below to active th TUN module:

   ```
   sudo /sbin/modprobe tun
   ```
2. Install OpenConnect:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openconnect
   ```
3. Connect to VPN, run:

   ```
   sudo openconnect yourvpn.example.com
   ```

Try this link it helped me  : http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/connect-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-ubuntu/

Comment: Cool @KevinBowen  will folllow that

Comment: Thanks; this saved my day!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not have to do the first step though.

Comment: simple and works like magic!

Answer (score 19):

1. Install some VPN plug-ins for Network Manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-­get install network-manager-pptp network-manager-vpnc network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openconnect-gnome
   ```
2. If prompted for your password, type it, and press Enter.
3. If you're told that a package “is already the newest version,” ignore it and continue with the next command.
4. If asked to “continue [Y/n],” press Y, followed by Enter.
5. Open the connections settings dialogue, go to the *VPN* tab and add a new connection:

   [image]
6. Select “Cisco AnyConnect”:

   [image]

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits. Just the `network­-manager­-vpnc`. And the connection seems stable so far.

Comment: I tried this under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. The `VPN compatible Cisco Anyconnect (openconnect)` option is not available. It states the `...may not have correct VPN plug-in installed.`

Comment: Need to install `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome` which contains the required plug-ins.

Comment: Stupid question but I don't have the Icons on the top right on the bar (amongs which is the network connections one) any way to turn those on. Or a another way to get to the same options.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because one of the required configurations is "group name" and "group password". I have no idea what those should be and neither the official client or openconnect require them.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue earlier. I observed that `vpnagentd` does not load because of `libatk1` and `vpnui` does not load because of `libxml2`. Installing the 32-bit versions of these libraries resolves the issues. You should install `ia32-libs` to resolve the issue using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This should resolve the issue for you on Ubuntu 64 bit versions. I have tried it on Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

I just installed openconnect.  Works similarly to the anyconnect command line utility.

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Ubuntu 18.04, OpenConnect VPN client is available as an add-on to GNOME Control Center, as shown here:

[image]

To enable this add-on, you can search for 'openconnect' in ubuntu software center like so:

[image]

Then click on gnome control center and check the checkbox for 'OpenConnect VPN Client'.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I installed OpenConnect with the 
[instructions here.](https://faq.oit.gatech.edu/content/how-do-i-install-cisco-anyconnect-client-linux) 
Finally, I don't have to deal with that Cisco garbage!

Comment: Dang, that link is broken.

Comment: Here's an archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20110312103407/http://faq.oit.gatech.edu/content/cisco-anyconnect-installation-instructions-linux

I don't remember why exactly I used those instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you do want the Ciso Anyconnect client working take a look at [this blog](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/installing-cisco-anyconnect-on-64-bit-ubuntu). 
Just disable the Firefox Iced Tea web plugin and go to your VPN site. Have Ubuntu download the VPN installer and run the shell script. 
In my case Cisco Anyconnect VPN client was installed and available under the Internet section and works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stick with OpenConnect though.

Comment: The link is broken now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In my case`vpnagentd` would not load. Installing the packages

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5`

however, resolved the problem for me. The terminal promted the message to install these, when I tried to install `ia32-libs`, which seems to be obsolete.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what finally worked for me too (Ubuntu 15.04, 64-bit).  I actually found that information here: http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~jstern/uci_vpn_ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Here are procedure that worked for me on Ubuntu 64 bit desktop 14.04.3

```
sudo apt-get install -y lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libxml2:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
```

Now, I can ./vpnui to launch.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue earlier. I observed that `vpnagentd` does not load because of `libatk1` and `vpnui` does not load because of `libxml2`. Installing the 32bit versions of these libraries resolves the issues. You should install ia32-libs to resolve the issue using

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This should resolve the issue for you on Ubuntu 64bit versions. I have tried it on 11.10 and 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download ubuntu compatible anyconnect from https://its.gmu.edu/wp-content/uploads/anyconnect-linux64-4.10.00093-predeploy-k9.tar_-1.gz

2.then follow the steps as mentioned-
https://its.gmu.edu/knowledge-base/how-to-install-cisco-anyconnect-on-linux/