# OpenConnect VPN not in Network Manager in 16.04

Tags: network-manager, vpn, 16.04, openconnect

I have network-manager-openconnect-gnome installed, but there is no option for OpenConnect in Network Manager.  If I run

```
sudo openconnect vpn.work.com
```

And enter my details, I can connect to my work VPN, so openconnect is installed and working, but it just isn't showing up in Network Manager.

Comment: I'm having the same issue unfortunately

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/760864/no-more-anyconnect-compatible-vpn-transport-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 20):

ubuntu man page

VPN support
Network Manager VPN support is based on a plug-in system. If you need VPN support via network manager you have to install one of the following packages:

`network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-openconnect`

The network-manager-pptp plugin is installed by default.

On GNOME, you also need to install the -gnome packages for the VPN plugin you choose:

`network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-vpnc-gnome
network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

Comment: Did you miss the part where I said "I have network-manager-openconnect-gnome installed"?  The problem is that, unlike earlier versions of Ubuntu, this does not work.

Comment: @Chas.Owens i also have it installed, and this worked for me. After installing the packages and the gnome packages, it start showing on the vpn list

Answer (score 7):

This should generally be solved by restarting your machine, and if you don't want to do so try:

```
# reloads all new or changed systemctl units
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then

```
# restart the network daemon
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers here are correct based on the question. For completeness (since this seems to be the only question that comes up when googling the problem):

This will fix the issue on 16.04+

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

The `*-gnome` package is needed for the GUI components. Note that a reboot or restart of the network-manager.service is required in order to see the change.

*Update:* Added restart of network-manager service instead of reboot as per @lane

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` did the trick in lieu of a reboot for me.

Answer (score 3):

here is what fixed the issue on my ubuntu 18.10 installation:

after installing the network-manager pluings using

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

I had to **reboot** my system. simply restarting network-manager did not help, so it must be something else like a gnome component or so, that needs to be restarted as well

Answer (score 1):

I also have "grayed out VPN" in Network-Manager this is what I found 
(I'm Newbie)

On Ubuntu 16.04 the network-manager-openconnect and network-manager-openconnect-gnome plugins are not usable because they are to old to use with the current version of network-manager.

This is the english version of this guide from a german ubuntu support forum - [Fixing unusable network-manager-openconnect-plugin on Xenial Xerus](http://tomtomtom.org/networkmanager-openconnect/)

Unofficial built packages are available here:

http://tomtomtom.org/networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_i386.deb

http://tomtomtom.org/networkmanager-openconnect_1.1.93-1_amd64.deb

NOTE: You won´t get any security updates for this! It is just a workaround until the packages will have been fixed in the official repository!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem. Couldn't start `sudo apt-get network-manager-openconnect`
problem - have no candidate for 'openconnect'

Solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openconnect/daily
sudo apt-get update
```

Source - https://launchpad.net/~openconnect/+archive/ubuntu/daily and try to install.