# OpenConnect not shown as an option in Network Manager in 20.04

Tags: gnome, network-manager, vpn, openconnect

I have network-manager-openconnect-gnome installed, but there is no option for OpenConnect in Network Manager. I am aware of [this past question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762183/openconnect-vpn-not-in-network-manager-in-16-04) for Ubuntu 16.04. On 20.04, I have done the following + reboot without getting it to work:

`sudo apt-install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

The VPN options I currently have are:
vpn options
[image]

Any idea why that could be? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a little older, the answer in case someone needs it:

Something in the system update borked things up, you need a clean install

Remove:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get --purge remove openconnect network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
sudo apt autoremove
```

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

Comment: Nope!  That did not help on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue which seems to have been addressed by restarting the network manager:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Probably same if rebooting.