# L2TP/IPSec VPN connection on Ubuntu 17.10 - Connection failed: Activation of network connection failed

Tags: network-manager, vpn

Despite considering all the following posts,

[1] [L2TP IPsec VPN client on Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569763/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-14-10)
[2] [How to connect to L2TP over IPSec VPN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617785/how-to-connect-to-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpn)
[3] [How to connect to L2TP over IPSec VPN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617785/how-to-connect-to-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpntions/904217/unable-to-connect-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-from-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)
[4] [l2tp/ipsec problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931586/l2tp-ipsec-problem#939597)
[5] [Can´t connect VPN using network-manager-l2tp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965593/can%C2%B4t-connect-vpn-using-network-manager-l2tp)
[6] [L2TP/IPsec NetworkManager plugin using only username, password and PSK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679568/l2tp-ipsec-networkmanager-plugin-using-only-username-password-and-psk)

I have been unable to set up a connection to my university's VPN.

Although strongswan and network-manager-l2tp are running, and all data (gateway/vpn ip, username, password, pre-shared key, phase1 & phase2 algorithms) are entered, I get the error message that the "Connection failed: Activation of network connection failed."

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**

*ike-scan*
terminal output:

> 130.82.18.20  Main Mode Handshake returned HDR=(CKY-R=e8f536147acee1d4) SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration=28800) VID=4048b7d56ebce88525e7de7f00d6c2d3c0000000 (IKE Fragmentation)

Thus, I have set the "Advanced Options"-Tab to:
Phase 1 = 3des-sha1-modp1024
Phase 2 = 3des-sha1
[no UDP encapsulation]

*system xl2tpd*

Stopping the system xl2tpd in the terminal hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution/workaround to my problem was basically described in this answer to a similar question:

[How do I install the Cisco Anyconnect VPN client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154699/how-do-i-install-the-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client#154797)

Running

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

and configuring the VPN with the newly available ''Cisco Anyconnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)'' did its job.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using network-manager-l2tp-1.2.8 and network-manager-l2tp-gnome-1.2.8 packages that are available in the default Ubuntu 17.10 repository.

Have you tried stopping and disabling the system xl2tpd ? More details in the README.md file :

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp#issue-with-not-stopping-system-xl2tpd-service

What is the output of running ike-scan.sh script against your university's VPN server? You can find more details on the following page:

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues#querying-vpn-server-for-its-supported-ipsec-ikev1-algorithms

After seeing the output of ike-scan.sh I can advise what the phase1 & phase2 algorithms should be.

Also from the [README.md](https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp#debugging) file, you could look at the `journalctl --boot` output to help with the debugging, alternatively after issuing the following, try performing a VPN connection, which will then result in debugging info going to the terminal  :

```
sudo killall -TERM nm-l2tp-service
sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-l2tp-service --debug
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, none of your hints solved my problem. Please see the edits to my original post above.

Comment: The issue is a bug/side effect as a result of using a weak pre-shared key.

Comment: Sorry prematurely sent the last comment, as hitting the return key results in an 'Add Comment'.

A workaround was added in the following commit : https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/commit/900233275bf07886dd6161bf9a5de4c62b1bd60e , the issue is that the PSK warning has an exit status of an error and after 10 attempts it still has an error and nm-l2tp then decides to exit.

Comment: If you are using libreswan, you could try switching to strongswan as I believe the "WARNING: using a weak secret (PSK)" message is from libreswan. Alternatively you could build from sourcecode which has the workaround commit, see the following page for building instructions : https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Building

Comment: Forgot to mention, the "using a weak secret (PSK)" message happens if the PSK is less than 8 characters.